# How to sort versioning info

Tags: php, version-control, version

What's the right way, to handle versioning indicators like `2.4` or `2.4.0.9` etc. to get the ability of sorting versions.

PHP says, that `1.3.4` is not a valid integer, but also a non-valid number.

```
array('2.4','2.3.4','2.4.0.9')
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

PHP has a [version_compare](http://php.net/version_compare) function. Use [usort](http://php.net/usort) to sort it. Like following. :)

```
$a = array('2.4','2.3.4','2.4.0.9');
usort($a, 'version_compare');
```

Comment: @Serjaru It [works pretty well](https://ideone.com/OiPFdr#comments). Could you elaborate what do you mean by _this dont work_? Could you show me reproducible code?

Answer (score 7):

Or, just use [**natsort**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php):

```
$array = array('2.4','2.16.6','2.3.4','2.4.0.9');
natsort($array);
print_r($array);

#Array ( [2] => 2.3.4 [0] => 2.4 [3] => 2.4.0.9 [1] => 2.16.6 )
```

Comment: `natsort` is a bad choice if versions may contain `-RC1` or other non-numeric data: version_compare will put RC versions before the stable one (ex: "Twig-1.0.0-RC1", "Twig-1.0.0-RC2", "Twig-1.0.0") where `netsort` will return a wrong "Twig-1.0.0", "Twig-1.0.0-RC1", "Twig-1.0.0-RC2"

Answer (score 5):

Storing it as a string allows you to make use of the [`version_compare()`](http://php.net/version_compare) function:

```
$versions = array('2.4','2.3.4','2.4.0.9');
usort($versions, 'version_compare');
```

Comment: I think I answerd the `usort` version before you. You edited later. :P